# QuantileTransform before or after long-to-wide format transformation?

Tags: anomaly-detection, normalization

I perform the following steps:

1. Perform quantile transform
2. Transform it from wide to long format
3. Train the anomaly detection model on the wide-format data

Will there be some significant change if I, instead, first perform a wide-to-long transform, and after perform the quantile transform?

Since the normalization is column-based, I understand, that the average will be slightly different across the columns, so the normalization might produce a bit different results. But would it really affect the results a lot, or it does not really matter?

**Example of data**:

*Features*: daily temperature, daily number of routes taken by the machine, daily movements in some parts of the machine (eg. number of switches).

Data contains a lot of outliers, that was motivation to select Quantile Transform.

Analysis will be done on 4-days window, hence the transformation to the wide format.

For example, consider one feature in the long format. If I perform some normalization procedure on this feature in the long format, all the numbers will be taking into account for computing std/mean/quantiles/...

```
Temperature
===========
15
21
23
30
24
14
30
19
20
23
31
19
```

However, if I transform to the long format:

```
Temperature_1   Temperature_2   Temperature_3   Temperature_4
=============   =============   =============   =============
15              21              23              30
24              14              30              19
20              23              31              19
```

So, now, if apply the same normalization procedure, it would calculate the statistics (std/mean/quantile depending on the chosen method) on each column separately.

Would it be safe to assume that in case of relatively big amount of data (eg. 100,000-500,000 rows) these differences would not matter, or is it safer to first perform the normalization, and then transform the data to the wide format?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some detailed explanation of the data and the problem you're trying to solve. The question as it is is very difficult to understand

Comment: @Leevo I tried to add more explanation to the question. But otherwise, the question is for now purely theoretical, so I cannot really provide more specifics.